# Waiting for more than one conditional in ElasticSearch:

Tags: elasticsearch

we can use following endpoint to wait for some event:

```
GET /_cluster/health?wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=50s
```

Is it possible to wait for two conditions, something like
`GET /_cluster/health?wait_for_status=yellow&wait_for_nodes=10&timeout=50s`
?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it works on my cluster.

```
GET /_cluster/health?wait_for_status=yellow&wait_for_nodes=13&timeout=5s
```